# Converting mixed internal and inline styles to internal

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following table with some internal and inline styles. It worked for me, but recently I noticed that table formatting is broken (inline styles was overridden by styles of main site and stopped working, only internal style for fonts are applied).
How to correctly convert these mixed internal and inline styles to internal? Would it be better use ID selectors instead of class?

CSS:
`table.myTable td, th { font-size:14px; }`

HTML:

```
<table class="myTable" style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">..</td>
            <th>aaaa</th>
            <th>bbbb</th>
            <th>cccc</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: this css works for me:

```
table.myTable {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.myTable th, table.allsizes td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}
table.myTable td,th {padding: 5px;}
table.myTable td,th {font-size: 14px;}
```

---

```
<table class="myTable">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "internal styles"?

Comment: internal style - css goes inside the head tags. My template have no html, head and body tags, so I put css in body (so consider it "internal")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.myTable {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.myTable th, table.allsizes td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}
table.myTable td,th {padding: 5px;}
table.myTable td,th {font-size: 14px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use IDs if you are going to apply a style in multiple areas on a single page. If your styles are broken then set a class in your `<head>` tag or in your external style sheet file and apply your attributes there. That way you avoid any conflicts.

Keep it simple and try to do all of your styling in an external style sheet and use classes if you are going to apply you attributes more than once. If you have an iframe that you are competing with then you can try the `!important` feature - Not the most elegant solution but if it is not applied to the above css outside the iframe then it will work.

Another better solution is to use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the css using the .css() function like so: `$(".myTable").css( "font-size", "14px" );`. Or, if you can, give your table a unique class name that does not conflict with any css class name given you the above iframe.

Comment: the content placed in main site inside frame. html, head, body tags cannot be used.

Comment: Are you saying that your HTML is within an iFrame and CSS from the above page is conflicting with what is in your iFrame?

Comment: Yes, the parent page(main site) contains an **iframe**, and my HTML page is actually the child page called within this iframe. And CSS from main site may possibly conflict with my CSS. Sometimes table formatting restores to normal and everything looks correct.

Comment: The above CSS is just an example. The syntax is correct, but you will have to determine exactly which attribute you want to add to your class. I have updated my answer to reflect the font attribute that you have in your question.